# Rotate Large bitmap using matrix

Tags: android, bitmap

When i rotate my large bitmap using matrix so application crash,i don't want to using canvas.
i am using below code,please help me Thanks

```
Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
rotateRight.postRotate(90);
rotateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                        bm.getHeight(), rotateRight, true);
```

See below logcate

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:924)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:901)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:833)
at com.insta.fragment.HomeFragment.rotateBitmap(HomeFragment.java:1363)
at com.insta.fragment.HomeFragment.getBitmap(HomeFragment.java:1376)
at com.insta.customcontrol.CameraPreview$3.onPictureTaken(CameraPreview.java:447)
at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:998)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you please paste your stack trace?

Comment: You need to scale your Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set [options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) for that

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length,options);
```

more explanations at [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

OR try with below code

```
            try {
            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length,o);

            //The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
            final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale=1;
            while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                scale*=2;

            //Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            Bitmap finalBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length,o2);
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
         }
```

Comment: It's working perfact..first i scal bitmap after rotate bitmap using my code..thank you very much..