# Android - ImageView.getDrawingCache() is returning null

Tags: android

I need to get a Bitmap from ImageView, but when I call imageView.getDrawingCache(), I get a NullPointerException. My code is as follows:

```
private void getBitmapFromImageView(Bitmap bitmap)
{  
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setRotation(90); //do something to the imageView

    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache();

    bitmap.recycle();

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Did u find the solution to this problem??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some transformation on a bitmap, in my opinion, the following way could be more convenient.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// Apply your transformations here
matrix.postRotate(90);

Bitmap transformed = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: I know, but the problem with this solution is that I need to work with images from the phone at full resolution, and your code would throw an OutOfMemoryError. What's the best solution then?

Comment: @fergaral [Have you looked at this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26795040/1841194)

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to scale the image, what I want is to rotate the image at its full resolution

Comment: @fergaral Would you like to do it *manually* by `getPixel()` and `setPixel` through a loop?

Comment: Maybe. What I have done is to extract the image's pixels to a bidimensional array, and then using a for loop, set the new image's pixels to the elements of that array, but when I create the bidimensional array, an OutOfMemoryError is thrown

Comment: @fergaral Don't use another array, just apply rotation on the bitmap object itself.

Comment: Yes, but if the bitmap is, let's say... 1366x768 pixels, if I rotate it to get dimensions of 768x1366 pixels, doing setPixel(i, j, getPixel(j, i)) wouldn't cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @fergaral Yes you're right, but I'm sorry, I've no idea

Comment: I also don't know. The thing is that if I keep 2 bitmaps simultaneously on memory, I get OOM